# Ubuntu 14.04 D-link Dns323

Tags: 14.04, networking

I've been trying to connect to my dns323. I use to have it connected through my wireless router but i moved and no longer have internet but still want to be able to connect to my hard drives in the dns323. I have a work group switch just don't know how to set everything up to get it in working order. if anyone could help me out that would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Probably used dhcp to get its address. If you still have the router plug that bag in and it should be assigned an ip address otherwise you will need to set your pc network card to the same subnet, 192.168.0.x the nas box will have given itself 192.168.0.32 so dont use that one.

The manual can be found [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dlink.com%2F-%2Fmedia%2FConsumer_Products%2FDNS%2FDNS%2520323%2FManual%2FDNS_323_Manual_v1_5_en.pdf&ei=r6DLVLe2B8uqyATPjYKAAQ&usg=AFQjCNEXrEt5Qevruy9DT7KolUOSJ2ynLQ&sig2=VV5TZ8NdPccPhevjH3Lakg&bvm=bv.84607526,d.aWw)